# Title of Poul Anderson's sequel to Darker Than You Think?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, poul-anderson

Wikipedia's article on *[Darker Than You Think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darker_Than_You_Think)*, a fantasy novel written in the 1940s by Jack Williamson, about a secret war between mankind and werewolf-like shapeshifters, claims Poul Anderson wrote a short story sequel during the '90s.

Does anyone know the title of this short story? Wikipedia doesn't tell, and a quick Google didn't help me either.

Comment: His short fiction output in the 90s was quite limited.  Take a gander at this and see if anything rings a bell: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3

Answer (score 6):

In 1996, Roger Zelazny edited *[The Williamson Effect](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50013)*—a volume of fiction, criticism, and poetry honoring Jack Williamson.  Poul Anderson contributed a poem and a novelette called "[Inside Passage](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66020)," which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I suppose you don't have an outline of what the novelette is about? Again, my google-fu fails me.